# Rails best_in_place gem not detecting mouse event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, inline

I am trying to implement inline editing using the best_in_place gem. I am using devise and have my user profile show route as the following: `get '/profile/:username' => 'profile#show', as: 'user'`

Here is my application.js tree:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery3
//= require best_in_place
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

In my assets/javascripts/users.coffee I have the following

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

This is the tag I am using on the view: `<%= best_in_place @profile_data, :first %>`

The page renders successfully but I am unable to click the field to edit it. It stays static even with the best_in_place tag.

Comment: Anything showing up in your browser console log? Can you confirm that best_in_place.js is properly loading in the Network debugger tab?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to put `require best_in_place` before your `require_tree` because your javascript/users.coffee needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Reolace the `rails-ujs` to `jquery_ujs` and follow the order

```
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require best_in_place
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

and use `jQuery` code instead of `coffee` (if you have not any problem)

```
// application.js
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Activating Best In Place */
    jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

Let me know you helped this like `jQuery` otherwise I will remove that answer.